# Problema con la respuesta de una request a la hora de implementar la funcionalidad para enviar imagenes

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

El objetivo del codigo es poder enviar un objeto en el cual ademas de la informacion del mismo viene acompañado de una imagen, esto para luego enviarlo a una base de datos. El **problema ocurre en la respuesta de la peticion** en el js, le hice un console.log y en el cual me llega un objeto con status *~500 Internal Server Error~*, tambien imprimi en consola cuando paso esa respuesta a json, esta vez el error es inmenso, pero puedo rescatar lo siguiente *~message: "Failed to parse multipart servlet request", path: "/products/clothes"~*

Este es mi dao (data access object) que utilizo en el controlador:

```java
package com.prj.cloments.dao;

import com.prj.cloments.models.Clothes;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ClothesDaoImp implements ClothesDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Clothes> getClothes() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("FROM Clothes", Clothes.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Clothes getClothesById(Integer id) {
        return entityManager.find(Clothes.class, id);
    }

    public void deleteClothesById(Integer id) {
        Clothes clothes = entityManager.find(Clothes.class, id);
        if (clothes != null)
            entityManager.remove(clothes);
    }

    public void createClothes(Clothes clothes) {
        // System.out.println(clothes.getBrand() + " " + clothes.getCategory());
        entityManager.persist(clothes);
    }
}
```

El controlador en cuestion:

```java
@RestController
@Controller
@RequestMapping("products")
public class ClothesController {

    @Autowired
    private ClothesDao clothesDao;

    @PostMapping("/clothes")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createClothes(@ModelAttribute Clothes clothes, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
        // aca intente ver que me llegaba por consola, pero nunca se imprimio
        System.out.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////////// " + clothes);
        System.out.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////////// " + image);
        try {
            // guarda la imagen en la carpeta images dentro de static
            String fileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
            // Ruta donde guardar la imagen
            String filePath = "./src/main/resources/static/images/" + fileName; 
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), image.getBytes());

            // asigna la ruta de la imagen al objeto Clothes
            clothes.setImage(fileName);

            clothesDao.createClothes(clothes);

            // Retorna una respuesta exitosa si todo va bien
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Clothes created successfully");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading image");
        }
    }
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('btn-add-clothes').addEventListener('click', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const clothes = {
        'name': document.getElementById('txtName').value,
        'size': document.getElementById('txtSize').value,
        'price': document.getElementById('txtPrice').value,
        'brand': {
            "id": document.getElementById('txtBrand').value,
        },
        'category': {
            "id": document.getElementById('txtCategory').value,
        }
    };
    
    if (document.getElementById('txtImage').files.length > 0) {
        clothes.image = document.getElementById('txtImage').files[0]
    }
    
    console.log(clothes);

    const settings = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: clothes,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
    };

    let res = await fetch('/products/clothes', settings);
    console.log(res);
    let data = await res.json();    
    console.log(data);
});
```

Este es el encabezado de mi formulario

```html
<form class="row g-3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/products/clothes}">
```

El objeto en cuestion se conforma de la siguiente forma:

```java
package com.prj.cloments.models;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Table(name = "clothes")
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
public class Clothes {

    @Id @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private String size;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;

}
```